# How can I correct this code to compute the factorial of 10 using java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

  public static int multiply(int z) {
      if(z > 0) {
          return z * multiply(z - 1);
      }else{
          return 0;
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int answer = multiply(10);
    System.out.println(answer);
  }

}
```

I have some issues running this code but when I trying it with addition function it does work

Comment: Use `return 1` in case you reached `z=0`, otherwise you multiply `10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0`, which is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [progman in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72293958/how-can-i-correct-this-code-to-compute-the-factorial-of-10-using-java/72293993#comment127720757_72293958), just change 0 to 1 in your if-statement and return 1 in the else statement. This way, you don't multiply with 0 at the end.

For example:

```
  public static int multiply(int z) {
      if(z > 1) {
          return z * multiply(z - 1);
      }else{
          return 1;
      }
  }
```